# How to get time avg data in Excel?

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, average

I have an excel sheet containing two Columns A (Timestamp) & Column B (value).

```
          A                  B
     TIMESTAMP             VALUE
     -----------------------------

1     1/1/2018 0:00:16     14.78

2     1/1/2018 0:00:18     14.79

3     1/1/2018 0:00:20     14.8

4     1/1/2018 0:00:22     14.8
```

The frequency of data is 2 sec. How can I get avg values of every 5 mins duration?

Comment: The duration between data points  (0:00:18) and data point 3 (0:00:19) is not 2 seconds...

Comment: this must be type mistake. however thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Then you need to check what is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure i this will help:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long, Count As Long
    Dim Average As Double, Total As Double
    Dim CurrentTime As Date, Plus5Minutes As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            CurrentTime = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Plus5Minutes = DateAdd("n", 5, CurrentTime)
            Count = 1
            Total = .Range("B" & i).Value

            For y = i + 2 To LastRow

                If .Range("A" & y).Value < Plus5Minutes Then
                    Count = Count + 1
                    Total = Total + .Range("B" & y).Value
                Else
                    .Range("C" & y - 1).Value = Total / Count
                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]